# Get items from list between two items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<string>` which looks like the following code below.

I need to collect the data between the `{` and `}` I'm not sure how I should proceed, so any information would be appreciated.

```
send 1,
wait 200,
loop 5 {,
send 2,
wait 200,
},
send 3,
loop 2 {,
send a,
wait 50,
}
```

Comment: A list as what? A list of strings? A `ListBox`? Please be clearer.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Sorry, I wrote List<string> (List String) but for some reason it didn't include the <> in the post.

Comment: Is each line of the above a separate `String` in the `List`? If not, how is it broken up in the list?

Comment: On above is that one of the element in your List<string> instance?

Comment: @LukeWillis Yes, each line is a seperate string.

Comment: Are the braces nested at all?

Comment: @Ezzy Please, next time, show us **what have you tried**, this will help the answers to be more what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexKevler I can't rollback (yet) because of my question, but... before editing, please read more in the comment

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
var firstIndex = list.FindIndex(r=> r.Contains('{'));
var secondIndex = list.FindIndex(r=> r.Contains('}'));
var result = list.Skip(firstIndex + 1).Take(secondIndex - (firstIndex +1));
```

The result would be:

[image]

The first version of the question didn't has multiple segments specified, I guess it was add in the grace period. The above version of the answer would work with a single segment of the string. To get it to work with multiple segments, a loop could be used like:

```
List<string> matchedItems = new List<string>();
List<string> listToWorkOn = new List<string>(list);
while(listToWorkOn.Any())
{
    var firstIndex = listToWorkOn.FindIndex(r => r.Contains('{'));
    var secondIndex = listToWorkOn.FindIndex(r => r.Contains('}'));
    matchedItems.AddRange(listToWorkOn.Skip(firstIndex + 1).Take(secondIndex - (firstIndex + 1)));
    listToWorkOn = listToWorkOn.Skip(secondIndex + 1).ToList();
}
```

`matchedItems` would result in `4` items from the list.

Comment: Oh, the miracles of LINQ... This is much shorter than my answer... :-) But does it work with more than one section as in the original question?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, no it doesn't, I didn't see the multiple sections in the question when it was posted

Comment: really good answer for a really "not-good" question.

Comment: @Habib I guess you could call this in a loop throwing away the part of the list you've alread examined?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, yeah just added that, but it looks really ugly.

Comment: @Habib Well, it still *looks* more elegant than my code :-D

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
int n = 0;
while (n < list.Count)
{
    List<string> everythingBetweenBraces = new List<string>();
    if (list[n].EndsWith("{");
    {
        n++;
        while (list[n] != "}");
        {
            everythingBetweenBraces.Add(list[n]);
            n++;
        }
        n++; // Don't forget to jump to the next line after }
    }

    ...
}
```

This checks whether the current line ends with `{` and if so, adds everything to a new list until  `}` is found on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var s = new List<string>
        {
            "send 1",
            "wait 200",
            "loop 5 {send 2 wait 200}",
            "send 3",
            "loop 2 { send a, wait 50 }"
        };

foreach (var element in s)
{
    if(element.Contains("{"))
    {
        var index = element.IndexOf("{")+1;
        var lastIndex = element.IndexOf("}") - index;
        var sub = element.Substring(index, lastIndex).Trim();
        Console.WriteLine(sub);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice the subtle difference between your list and his? In your list, the "block" is in one line. In his list it is not. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
var list = new List<string>
        {
            "send 1",
            "wait 200",
            "loop 5 {",
            "send 2",
            "wait 200",
            "}",
            "send 3",
            "loop 2 {",
            "send a",
            "wait 50",
            "}"
        };

var indexes = list.Select((x, index) =>
        {
            if (x.Contains('{') || x.Contains('}')) return index;
            return -1;
        }).Where(x => x != -1).ToList();
var ranges = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i += 2)
{
      ranges.Add(indexes[i],indexes[i+1]);
}
var resultList = list.Where((item, index) => 
                            ranges.Any(r => index > r.Key && index < r.Value))
                     .ToList();
```

And output:

[image]